# SQL Browser Service Stops After One Minute

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am encountering an issue with the SQL Browser service where the service will start, run for around 60-90 seconds and then stop. No error is logged, the event logs show three informational entries:

> The SQL Server Browser service has started.
>
> The SQL Server Browser is enabling SQL instance and connectivity discovery support.
>
> The SQL Server Browser service has shutdown.

Things I've tried so far:

- Removing and reinstalling SQL Browser.
- Repairing the SQL installation.
- Changing the logon account for SQL Browser.
- If I run the browser in console mode from the command line (sqlbrowser.exe -c) then it runs fine and does not shut down.
- Verified no antivirus is terminating the service.
- Turned off Windows Firewall just to be sure.
- Restarted machine.
- Applied latest updates.

I've run out of ideas. Is there a log file for the Browser service somewhere that might give some clues? Has anyone encountered this issue before?

SQL: 2017 Standard Edition

Windows: 2019 Core

Installed Features: SQL Engine, SSRS, Integration Services, Browser

Comment: Is there anything in Local security policy or group policy that might stop services? A scheduled task? 3rd party management tool? Does the event log show which user account issues stop command?

Comment: Is it possible that when Windows starts the service it will use some option that is configured with a value causing the problem and when you run the command line it will start SQL Browser with default options that run fine? I haven't worked with windows core and don't know how to check the options configured for the services though.

Comment: One more thing: do the **The SQL Server Browser service has started.** and 
**The SQL Server Browser is enabling SQL instance and connectivity discovery support.** informational entries appear on the log when you run the command line too?

Comment: @vonPryz No scheduled tasks, same GP as other SQL Servers without this problem (different OS though), and no stop command is recorded in the logs. It seems the service executable is shutting down, the service isn't being stopped via Service Control Manager.

Comment: @Ronaldo The same messages are logged when running via cmdline, and the service is configured identically to other SQL Servers without this problem.